# ubuntu 20: ctrl + alt + t doesnt focus window

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal

for some reason after a few updates and driver changes, opening terminal doesn't put terminal in focus, instead giving me a notification toaster popup that terminal is ready. I have searched in dconf and cant find any options. How can I get terminal to be pushed to top of my applications when opened?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I switched back to proprietary NVIDIA drivers from noveau and updated and upgraded apt. after a reboot terminal now has the desired behavior.